# Splunk - How to count occurrences of a string by an extracted field?

Tags: regex, splunk

I have such log-entries:

*First entry:*

```
"abc","Id":"XYZ12"},{"lat":55},{"lat":45}{"lat":59}
```

*Second entry:*

```
"abc","Id":"YZA56"},{"lat":23},{"lat":101}
```

What I now want to get is the number of occurences of string `"lat"` per `Id`.

So in the end I would like to get a statistics like this one:

```
Id occurences
XYZ12 3
YZA56 2
```

How can I do this in Splunk? I would know how to get the `Id` and then count all the events by this `Id`. But I do not know what to do when I want to do the exercise upon..

Can someone support here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume no fields are extracted automatically.

Use the `rex` command to extract fields.  We'll do two extractions: one for 'Id' and another for 'lat'.  The second uses `max_match=0` to allow for multiple hits.

```
index=foo
| rex "Id\\\:\\\"(?<Id>[^\\\"]+)"
| rex max_match=0 "lat\\\":(?<lat>\d+)"
| eval occurences=mvcount(lat)
| table Id occurences
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks a lot! I only extended the query by `| stats count by Id` and got what I want!

Comment: Only one more question. Should it not be possible to make a timechart as well by using this at the end? `|timechart span=10m count by Id`.  This does not show me a result in contrast to the `stats`command upon.

Comment: The `timechart` command can't count occurrences within a multi-value field such as `lat`.

Comment: Is there another way to do this or is it just not possible?

Comment: The follow-up questions appear to heading in a different direction.  Consider posting a new question with the full query as it currently exists and the desired output.